# Problemas en algunos casos con el mínimo de 6 caracteres al editar

Tags: bug, ediciones

Por una experiencia en una pregunta que yo mismo he formulado, me he dado cuenta de que en el caso de la edición de una línea de código, el límite mínimo de 6 caracteres para la edición puede ser un problema.

Todos sabemos que basta que haya solo un carácter erróneo en una línea de código, para que el comando o la aplicación no funcione, y el error recibido a veces puede hacernos confundir en lugar de aclararnos donde está el problema.

Pues bien, en mi caso, he querido editar una respuesta, por una línea de código, la cual era correcta y resolvió mi problema, pero tenía un carácter erróneo. Yo lo deduje y no le dí importancia, porque conociendo mi problema, era fácil de ver, pero luego pensé que esa respuesta le podía ser útil a otro usuario y se podría confundir.

Así que realicé la edición y me encontré con el mensaje de error de los 6 caracteres... así que decidí completar un poco más la respuesta con una frase, pero la edición fue rechazada supuestamente por "alejarme del objetivo de la pregunta". Y digo yo, suponiendo que ha habido una razón lógica para rechazarla y no ha sido de forma automática, ¿Como se podría corregir esa línea de código? ¿Realmente no vale la pena?

Comment: Yo hubiera pensado lo mismo, añadir una frase indicando el asunto para sobrepasar el límite, pero claro, está la otra cuestión y es la facilidad que tienen algunos usuarios para cerrar preguntas y rechazar ediciones.

Answer (score 1):

Si te refieres a esta edición https://es.stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/50557 yo fui uno de los que la rechazo

Mi motivo es por lo que la rechace fue el siguiente:

- Podías comentar al usuario que te respondió que tenia un error en el comando
- poner este texto: **"ya que no hay otro modo."** es como decir que si
  alguien tiene un problema muy similar al tuyo leer eso es como decir
  *"si esto no funciona ya no tienes solución"*
- La explicación breve de la sugerencia no esta del todo clara, *"Error en una letra del comando"*, si hubieses explicado un poco mas el motivo como poner *"Error en una letra del comando ya que en la guía oficial esta de la forma editada"*

Espero entiendas mi opinión, mis motivos y no lo tomes mal

Comment: En primer lugar, como dije, no le dí importancia porque aunque hubiera un error, lo deduje y me funcionó de todas formas, y fue más adelante que pensé que quizá no lo dedujeran otros usuarios como hice yo, pero ya la pregunta estaba cerrada, el usuario agradecido y la recompensa dada, por lo que no le ví mucho sentido comentarle el error en ese momento. Por el segundo punto, me refiero a que **después de usar el comando** el único modo de ver y copiar los archivos es por el terminal, y no solo lo he escrito yo, sino también el mismo usuario en un comentario posterior. (Continúo...)

Comment: (...Continúo) Por el tercer punto, el error no es solo porque no está exactamente como en la guía oficial, sino porque en mi caso, el volumen se llamaba en concreto "lv1" y el usuario se refería a mi caso. Como he explicado en este post, algún usuario podría descartar esa solución solo porque naturalmente ese código le de error, y no sepa que es solo por ese detalle, que se podría arreglar con una simple edición.

Comment: @Miguelw te sugiero hacer nuevamente la edición, pero te recomendaría que explicaras eso del nombre del volumen lv1, añadir una explicación que ese volumen puede ser diferente en diferentes maquinas etc., solo es para completar la respuesta y evitar confusiones con futuros usuarios

Comment: Para mi la respuesta está muy clara, y la única corrección necesaria es ese carácter. La explicación de por qué la he hecho, sigo sosteniendo que era clara de por sí, pero aún así, he hecho de nuevo la edición, ampliando el motivo donde corresponde.